# Эффект при клике

Tags: javascript, html, css, меню, эффекты

Нужно что бы при нажатии на бургер меню блок сдвигался и показывал меню(текст). Также что бы можно было задвинуть его обратно, более наглядно здесь:
https://www.figma.com/proto/g71KyTvuEmT2ptSrYtfgadq1/Untitled?node-id=1%3A2&scaling=min-zoom

Максимум который я смог достичь:

```js
$(".header").click(function(){

$(this).css({
  "right":"300px"
});
  $(this).dblclick(function(){
$(this).removeAttr("style");
  })
});
```

```css
.header{
position: absolute;
height: 1000px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
top: 10px;

background: linear-gradient(117.85deg, #444A59 0%, #10131A 100%);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header"></div>
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задумку, можно сделать так

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="menu-btn"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">home</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">works</a></div>
      <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">contact</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8smnw41/)